# Swift 3 UITableView Problems

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

My interface consists of two things inside my main ViewController: a label (the top half of the screen), and a table (the bottom half).

For the life of me, I cannot find a tutorial or example in Swift 3 + iOS 10 where a UITableView is successfully used, as opposed to a UITableViewController which takes up the entire screen.

What must be done to use a UITableView with dynamic cells in the bottom half of your interface?

I tried adding the UITableView, then creating a subclass of UITableViewController, but I was unable to select this in the UITableView's Custom Class -> Class dropdown. Apparently, I need to subclass UITableView, but I can find no examples of how to do this.

Comment: create hiearchy like --> UIViewController - uilabel (or use UItableview headerView) - UItableview

Comment: Why do you want to subclass UITableView? Are you following MVVM or MVC?

Comment: see this https://gist.github.com/BayPhillips/0d000d7c720c2417405d

Comment: I haven't even decided on MVC vs everything else. I just want to populate a UITableView with test data. If I use that gist example, how do I connect a UITableViewController to my UITableView?

Comment: @JohnD. you don't need to use the UITableViewController, you can use a viewController and connect the tableview to the vc as you connect the label, control + drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a standard `UIViewController` and drag a table view into the canvas.
- In IB connect the table view to the `IBOutlet` and delegate and datasource to the controller.

  ```
  class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { 

      @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!
      ...
  ```

Unlike `UITableViewController` you have to implement all relevant datasource and delegate methods.

Comment: But at this point, tableView is just a variable in MyViewController. Don't I need a separate class to be the UITableView's Custom Class -> Class?

Comment: No, the table view is a part of your view controller, a custom (sub)class is not needed.

Comment: Interesting. This is for a personal project, so I should be able to give it a try this weekend.

Comment: This was what I needed- that second bullet point of connecting the delegate and datasource. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At first , the UITableView and UITableViewController are not the same thing, the TableView is a view and TableViewController is a Controller withe a tableview inside.

If you are using UITableViewController you should drag a UITableViewController, and then change its class in the third tab on the top!

If you are using a basic ViewController and drag a TableView inside, you could get The TableView in the ViewController using an IBOutlet.@John D.

You can use normal ViewController and init a UITableView in the viewDidLoad and add it to the ViewController.

```
var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView = UITableView.init(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 300, height: 300, width:screenWidth))
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "NameListTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: nameListTableViewCellId)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

[image]

set the `tableview.delegate = self` and `tableview.datasource = self`,
using methods in the pic and lots other in the UITableViewDelegate and UITabelViewDataSource protocol to Custom your tableView!

hope this would help

Comment: That part isn't a problem, I'm able to drag a UITableView into my storyboard. But I don't know how to connect the UITableView with my class that extends UITableViewController to work with it.

Comment: I get it, don't extent tableview to custom a tableview, using the delegate and datasource  to custom a tableview in a ViewController.

Comment: And  the UITableViewController is just a ViewController with a full screen UITableView and  extend UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, it just  a quick way no difference with UIViewController + UITableView.